# mysql long text datatype in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing wap forum for my site in PHP mysql.Now in the descriptions of the forum i use `longtext` datatype.when user enters the description above 1500 characters its not inserted into database.I have searched for that and find something like

`TINYTEXT   256 bytes`

`TEXT           65,535 bytes    ~64kb`

`MEDIUMTEXT    16,777,215 bytes    ~16MB`

`LONGTEXT  4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB`

so why the description above 1500 characters is not inserted ? and what is the solution of this thing ?

Edit: The code being used for the insert (taken from comments):

```
$sql1="
    INSERT INTO 
        forum_top
        (catID,forumN,forumDescr,forum_time,uID,forum_attach) 
        VALUES ($cat_idd,'$top_namee','$top_descri','$tmform',$n_u_id,'$newfilename')"; 
if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
```

$top_descri comes from:

```
 $top_descri =nl2br(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['top_descri']));
```

I have solved it i use some function that check the length of the description and the limit of that function is 1500 chars so its stop working.Now working fine.

Comment: Could you post your insertion code?

Comment: My insertation code is :

    $sql1="INSERT INTO forum_top(catID,forumN,forumDescr,forum_time,uID,forum_attach)
    VALUES ($cat_idd,'$top_namee','$top_descri','$tmform',$n_u_id,'$newfilename')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

Comment: and yes there is no error dispalying only page stops loading...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your insert code that would cause it to drop anything over a certain length - at least not in the section you have posted here. Can you add to the question where the variables such as `$top_descri` come from and anything you are doing to them between getting the data from a (form? I assume) and isnerting them into the query?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are submitting the form using **GET** method? It has a limitation of around 2000 characters for the URL. You should be using **POST** instead.

Comment: i already used POST method.i have never passed forum description through URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is prone to **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**.

Example of using PDO:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_top(catID, forumN, forumDescr, 
                                       forum_time, uID, forum_attach) 
                      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $cat_idd);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $top_namee);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $top_descri);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $tmform);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $n_u_id);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $newfilename);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

***Remember to always sanitize your inputs. You'll never know some of the input contains single quotes.***

Comment: it should work, but the use of it has already been discourage by the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: `$top_descri = nl2br($_POST['top_descri']);` then pass `$top_descri` on the parameters.

Comment: try to look at this link, http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php